# Configuring Quarkus with Agroal for AWS RDS Proxy

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, quarkus, agroal

We've just started using AWS RDS Proxy for our lambdas. I'm trying to figure out the optimal Agroal configuration in Quarkus 3 for using this, to replace the Agroal pooled config that I had before.

I'm assuming that the below will work - in other words, that I need to specify `POOLLESS` and although I have to specify a `maxSize`, it doesn't matter what it is, because Agroal will just delegate all requests for connections to RDS Proxy?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {
    @Produces
    public AgroalDataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier dataSourceConfiguration = new AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier();

        dataSourceConfiguration
                .dataSourceImplementation(
                        AgroalDataSourceConfiguration.DataSourceImplementation.AGROAL_POOLLESS)
                .connectionPoolConfiguration()
                .maxSize(?) // Looks like I still have to have this?
                .connectionFactoryConfiguration()
                .jdbcUrl("redacted")
                .credential(new NamePrincipal("redacted"))
                .credential(new SimplePassword("redacted"));

        return AgroalDataSource.from(dataSourceConfiguration.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: you can with [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/datasource.adoc#activatedeactivate-datasources) looks like you need @Inject then use it though, yours looks like more of spring way which is different in quarkus, in quarkus you need to configure it via properties.

Comment: I was asking more about the interaction between Agroal and RDS proxy, but I didn't make that clear - have edited the question accordingly.